# What is the history of "may" being used to mean "must"?

Tags: etymology, auxiliary-verbs

According to (online) [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/may), "may" has the following two distinct definitions, among others

> 1 b: have permission to
>
> 4: SHALL, MUST —used in law where the sense, purpose, or policy requires this interpretation

[Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/may_1?q=may) does not seem to have the definition of may = shall, must.

What is the history of may being used to mean "must"?

Comment: The mother of Grok.

Comment: A link to the dictionary where you found this would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, _which_ 'Oxford dictionary'?

Comment: I've been in situations where a snarled "You may take your leave" etc is used to convey an order.

Comment: I found [this definition](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1229) in an online legal dictionary supporting the Merriam-Webster one.

Comment: The full (subscription-only) defn I-6b OED says *In the interpretation of statutes, it has **sometimes** been ruled that **may** is to be understood as equivalent to **shall** or **must.*** But their first recorded instance of this sense is 1715, which is nearly ***five centuries later*** than immediately-preceding defn I-6a *Expressing **permission or sanction**: be allowed (to do something) by authority, law, rule, morality, reason, etc.*

Comment: What's the only word that means mandatory? Here's what law and policy say about "shall, will, may, and must."  - https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/plain_language/articles/mandatory/

Comment: Patrick and User: Oops. Did I misunderstand? When I said "Legal language—what we call legalese—is the result of centuries of written tradition strictly within the legal profession," I was referring to the history. The OED reference is great. Glad someone posted it.

Comment: The book "Regularity in Semantic Change" (Traugott, Dasher) has a very long (17-page) discussion of the history of may/must and its changes in modality.

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of such (ab)use of these words. That finally explains to me why RFCs always explicitly reference https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119 for definitions of words I would have considered self-explanatory ...

Answer (score 15):

The OED dates this sense of the word back to 1715:

> Where a Statute directs the doing of a Thing for the sake of Justice or the publick Good, the Word *may* is the same as the Word *shall*; thus 23 H.6. says, the Sheriff may take Bail; this is construed, he shall; for he is compellable so to do.
>
> —*Reports of cases adjudg'd in the Court of King's bench*

Comment: Good find! Such laws that have this use of **may** are usually ones where several conditions are required for something being granted/issued. The laws often start with "*X **will** be issued by <an official> if the following conditions are met...*" and  end "*if the above conditions are met then X **may** be granted/issued.*"

Answer (score 1):

As a native UK speaker, I'd simply say that Merriam Webster is wrong.

The 1715 example just seems to be noting that when a statute says 'may', that - in the particular circumstances relating to the Sheriff - is the same as 'shall', because "he is compellable so to do".

If he wasn't compellable to do so, 'may' would not be the same as 'shall' or 'must'.

Even legally speaking, if someone tells me I 'may' use their swimming pool, that does not mean I 'must' or 'shall' do so - because I'm not under any obligation to go swimming whenever I can.

Comment: But this isn't asking about the everyday usage. Is OED also wrong (FumbleFingers' comment above)?

Comment: OED is not wrong insofar as it says that it has **sometimes** been **ruled** that a document containing *may* should be interpreted as if it had *shall* or *must* instead. A court would, however, so rule only rarely and hesitantly, when looking at the document **as a whole**, justice so requires. In doing so, the court would be aware that it is departing from the normal understanding of the word, in order to produce a fair result. It would be wrong to take the OED entry as implying that anybody deliberately uses the word that way in drafting legal documents.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, and as such wont have anything to say about how *may* for *shall* struck me as odd when reading it in this context.

But I am a native German speaker and we distinguish the verb *mögen* in indicative *ich mag* (I like, I may want to), subjunctive (Konjunktiv I) *ich möge* and, I guess you would also call it subjunctive (Konjunktiv II) *ich möchte*. The precise details of these modi are immaterial, here, but it's interesting that *möchte* (ca. "might") has come to be understood as a separate stem, not anymore related to *mögen*, but without a form for, or without a practical use for, the infinitive, probably for thousands of years now. It's common consensus that the stem was the same though, which is what I will go with, though I'm incubating doubts.

The point being, "Er möge Kaution annehmen" has the obligatory sense as in "He may take bail". This does sound a bit old fashioned. The apparently sarcastic tone is used colloquially as well, *Du möchtest den Müll raus bringen* "you may bring out the trash", perhaps as a variant of an archaic, high council like *mögest*, but built from the preterite *mochte*, thus implying precedent. This is showing how the different moods and aspects are deeply intertwined.

Proto-Indo-European as reconstructed in the articles of wikipedia had subjunctive and optative mood. One of these was built with an *-iH, *-ey suffix, and then some, notwithstanding Schwebelaut. Before or in Middle High German, terminal *-i* caused Umlautung in the nucleus (Sturm, stürmisch -- storm, stormy), depending on several factors.

Clearly, in English this ending would be subsumed by *y* when the velar g, still visible in Old English *magan*, became however lenited to *may*. Henceforth, the grammatical difference was lost as in many other cases of erroding English morphology. Whether the meaning was nevertheless kept in good memory, as in *you may go now*, or reinvented by statute in the 18th c. as other opinions suggest, I don't know.

The precise interpretation of the different modi and aspects is not always clear. If you said *the Sherrif can take bail*, this might be construed as a statement of fact, irregardless of the actuality, whereas Germann *kann sein* chiefly means "maybe" in colloquial speech, largely indistinct from *könnte sein* "could be", though in legalese, as far as I'm aware, the former leaves the decision to the discretion of the administrator subject only to moral obligations, whereas the latter would strictly imply modus irrealis and as such cannot confer obligation. Similarly *ich will* "I want", *ich werde* "I will, I become" and English *you will!* show's a striking difference. *mag sein* is literally "may be", too, but *das möchte wohl sein* (doesn't translate) again plays on the preterite, ca. "that's well expected, anything else would be far from acceptable" (as if *that must be*, but where to stick the *well*?). I mean to say, there were inherent uncertainties that lead to the errosion of this grammatical system. The optative is perhaps still seen in *I wanna*, while the usual example of optative aspect is *lemme* (or rather *let's*), but as a grammatical function it was already lost in almost all descendants from Indo-European long ago.

I want to say this has a desiderative aspect, which, when coming from an authority, implies obligation to the subordinate, when success of the order is in their *might* at all (*in der Macht stehen*; also cp. *Möglichkeit* "possibility", *möglich* "maybe", possibly conflated with *machbar* "make-able, feasable"). But the difference between "I want to go" or "Don't you want to go now!?!" is quite obvious, so I don't quite know what to call either of both aspects.

Comment: It's very interesting, but all in the 'comment' bracket: not directly answering the actual question. Which FumbleFingers' comment _does_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth there is an answer in paragraphs 4 and five. mood suffix \*-iH being subsumed in sound change under indicative, without however completely loosing the connotation. Did you miss that in the wall of text, criticizing my writing as borring, or do you consider that not an answer, perhaps wrong even? FF explains jack, merely hints at a possibly well founded answer in the considerations of some rulings; the dating from the OED is unreliable anyhow, as SvenYargs frequently shows.

Comment: And, if you imply that *because I said so* (of God, the wigs, the caretaker) is a valid answer, that's highly fallacious. If everyone, or a significant share of the population (the wigs, the caretaker, sarcastic mothers) said so, that remains to be shown, I agree. But I don't accept de novo ex machina (?) as an answer.

Comment: Outlining all the German may be circumstantial and mostly irrelevant, but it's a proof of work, meaning it allows those who are knowledgable enough to point out mistakes in the argument. You are just being salty because you cannot deny nor approve it :P

Comment: 'Clearly, in English this ending would be subsumed by y when the velar *g became however lenited.'  _But how do we know that the loaning didn't occur with immediate semantic change?_ 'Henceforth, the grammatical difference was lost as in many other cases of erroding English morphology. Whether the meaning was nevertheless kept in good memory, as in you may go now, or reinvented by statute in the 18th c. as other opinions suggest, I don't know.' _This just echoes / comments on existing answers. OED is considered pretty good on ELU, and way better than nothing._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't say anything about loaning. I do prefer to remain agnostic about such matters, for the sake of this venue. The comunis opinio is straight inheritence from Proto-Germanic along with settlers coming from the continent. Normalized Old English yet reads *g*, anyway. German serves only for analogy in this answer. Neither did I imply semantic change, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Loved reading all the comments  I was told back in 2011 that legalese was a language created by ancient scholars to trick/manipulate/con the average layman out of his hard earned very small and newish industrial revolution wage packet.

I was told that the language was very similar to English but with a handful of words with slight changes to their meaning, one of those words was MUST. I was told that in legalese MUST is equal to MAY, and therefore when you receive a bailiffs letter stating that you MUST pay £X by a certain date, what it’s really saying is you MAY pay £X on that particular date in question, the letters in legalese offers the layman a choice he didn’t know he had…

I have done as mentioned to bailiffs in the past, simply pointed out what I knew and told them I have decided to decline and believe me or not it works, or put it this way they’ve never been back!  So is my train of thought correct or have I just got lucky? Or am I chatting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416753)